# Navigation Properties Not Populated on POST Action MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I've run into this issue twice now, and I don't quite understand why.  I'm creating a wine in my database by posting a viewmodel back.  The Wine property of that viewmodel is populated correctly, but when I save the changes in the db, the navigation properties aren't populated - like I thought it would be.  I need this because, I pass this wine object into a method to add those navigation properties to my search index.

I've tried to re-query the database to a new variable, but that doesn't work either.  I'm really confused on this one - so any help would be great.  I ran into a very similar issue and didn't receive any answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801205/mvc-model-on-post-has-no-navigation-properties).  Other people have solved this by re-querying the db [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423267/mvc3-why-are-navigation-properties-null-on-postback) but that doesn't work for me.  The model populates fine on the GET request, but not on the post.

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
//[Authorize(Roles = "admin, producereditor")]
public ActionResult Create(NewWineViewModel nw)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        nw.Wine.Active = nw.IsRequest ? false : true;
        //keep nullable for requests.
        nw.Wine.ImporterID = nw.Wine.ImporterID == 0 ? null : nw.Wine.ImporterID;
        nw.Wine.VarTypeID = nw.Wine.VarTypeID == 0 ? null : nw.Wine.VarTypeID;
        nw.Wine.OriginID = nw.Wine.OriginID == 0 ? null : nw.Wine.OriginID;
        nw.Wine.AppID = nw.Wine.AppID == 0 ? null : nw.Wine.AppID;
        nw.Wine.VintageID = nw.Wine.VintageID == 0 ? null : nw.Wine.VintageID;

        nw.Wine.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
        nw.Wine.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        db.Wines.Add(nw.Wine);

        db.SaveChanges();

        var wineToIndex = db.Wines.Find(nw.Wine.WineID);
       // nw.Wine.QRUrl = WineUtils.MakeQRCode(nw.Wine);
        //db.SaveChanges();


        //Lucene.LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(db.Wines.Find(nw.Wine.WineID));


        if (nw.IsRequest)
        {
            nw.VOAVIRequest.WineID = nw.Wine.WineID;
            nw.VOAVIRequest.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            nw.VOAVIRequest.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            db.VOAVIRequests.Add(nw.VOAVIRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Requested");

            //redirect to "Request Submitted" page for new wines
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = nw.Wine.WineID });
    }

    ViewBag.VarTypeID = new SelectList(db.VarTypes, "VarTypeID", "Name").Default("Select a Varietal/Type", nw.Wine.VarTypeID.ToString());
    ViewBag.OriginID = new SelectList(db.Origins, "OriginID", "Name").Default("Select an Origin", nw.Wine.OriginID.ToString());
    ViewBag.AppID = new SelectList(db.Apps, "AppID", "Name").Default("Select an Appellation", nw.Wine.AppID.ToString());
    ViewBag.VintageID = new SelectList(db.Vintages, "VintageID", "Name").Default("Select a Vintage", nw.Wine.VintageID.ToString());
    ViewBag.ImporterID = new SelectList(db.Importers, "ImporterID", "Name").Default("Select an Importer", nw.Wine.ImporterID.ToString());
    if (User.IsInRole("producer"))
    {
        Producer currentProd = db.ProducerUsers.Find(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey).Producer;
        ViewBag.ProducerID = currentProd.ProducerID;
        ViewBag.ProducerName = currentProd.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.ProducerSelect = new SelectList(db.Producers, "ProducerID", "Name", nw.Wine.ProducerID);
    }
    return View(nw);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class NewWineViewModel
{

    public Wine Wine { get; set; }
    public VOAVIRequest VOAVIRequest { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequest { get; set; }

    public SelectList VarTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList Origins { get; set; }
    public SelectList Apps { get; set; }
    public SelectList Vintages { get; set; }
    public SelectList Importers { get; set; }

    public NewWineViewModel()
    {
        this.Wine = new Wine();
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class Wine :Updater
{
    public int WineID { get; set; }
    //public int WineTypeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Varietal/Type")]
    public int? VarTypeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Origin")]
    public int? OriginID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Appellation")]
    public int? AppID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Vintage")]
    public int? VintageID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Importer")]
    public int? ImporterID { get; set; }
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }
    public string Designate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Drink Window")]
    public string DrinkWindow { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Varietal Makeup")]
    public string VarietalMakeup { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Case Production")]
    public string CaseProduction { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Alcohol Content")]
    public double? AlcoholContent { get; set; }
    public string Winemaker { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Consulting Winemaker")]
    public string ConsultWinemaker { get; set; }
    public bool Sustainable { get; set; }
    public bool Kosher { get; set; }
    public bool Organic { get; set; }
    public bool Biodynamic { get; set; }
    public bool SalmonSafe { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ResidualSugar")]
    public double? RS { get; set; }
    public double? pH { get; set; }
    public string QRUrl { get; set; }


    public virtual WineType WineType { get; set; }

    public virtual VarType VarType { get; set; }
    public virtual Origin Origin { get; set; }
    public virtual App App { get; set; }
    public virtual Vintage Vintage { get; set; }
    public virtual Importer Importer { get; set; }
    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<POS> POSs { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Doc> Docs { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BodyList { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've got a workaround where I the below:
nw.Wine.Producer = db.Producers.Find(nw.Wine.ProducerID);

This seems to work and suggest it has to do with binding somewhere, but this is a pretty bad workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Wine property of that viewmodel is populated correctly, but when I
>   save the changes in the db, the navigation properties aren't populated
>   - like I thought it would be.

Saving the changes to the database never *loads* data from the DB and therefore cannot populate navigation properties. What you expect in this specific case is that *lazy loading* will propulate the navigation properties (that are `virtual` in your model) as soon as you access them. That's actually a separate query for each navigation property.

Now, the problem is that lazy loading cannot work in your POST action because the model binder has instantiated the `nw.Wine` entity. But the model binder (which doesn't know anything about Entity Framework) doesn't create a lazy loading proxy object for the Wine entity, but just uses `new` (or maybe some instantiation with the reflection API). A lazy loading proxy is required to have lazy loading working.

If you would create the `nw.Wine` entity manually you could create a lazy loading proxy by using...

```
nw.Wine = db.Wines.Create();
```

...instead of using `nw.Wine = new Wine();`. Your code would work then as you expect and lazy loading would populate the navigation properties after you have attached/added the entity to the EF context.

The solution you have proposed in your comment...

```
nw.Wine.Producer = db.Producers.Find(nw.Wine.ProducerID)
```

...(and the same for the other navigation properties) is the correct way in my opinion. Alternativly you could use explicit loading:

```
db.Entry(nw.Wine).Reference(w => w.Producer).Load();
```

But is all three cases - lazy loading (if it would work), using `Find` or using explicit loading - the same database query will be executed. So, performance-wise there is no difference.

Lazy loading in your GET action works because - I guess - you are loading the wine entity from the DB...

```
var wine = db.Wines.Find(id); // or maybe `Single` or `First`, etc.
```

...and loading the entity from the database creates a lazy loading proxy.

Comment: Great explanation.  Thanks a ton.  I'm going to put this in now.  Thanks for the clear and concise explanation.  I really appreciate it.